# Puppeteer selector not being found

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am having an issue debugging why a query selector is not being clicked - I can search for it in chrome and also if use the document.querySelector() in the dev tools it finds the query, which makes me believe that it is right, however it is not pressing it and just times out

Click Method:

```
async function click(page, selector, timeout) {
await beforeAction(page, timeout);
await page.waitForSelector(selector);
await page.waitFor(200);
await page.click(selector);
}
```

Main Method That gets executed:

```
async function existingStart(page) {
await loadCookies(page);
await page.goto(
    "https://mc.s7.exacttarget.com/cloud/#app/Email/C12/Default.aspx?entityType=none&entityID=0&ks=ks%23Content"
    , {
        waitUntil: 'load',
        timeout: 0
    }
);
await page.waitFor(200);
const contentBuilderFrame = await findFrame(page, "contentbuilder");
const searchField = await contentBuilderFrame.$(".contentsearch > input");
searchField.focus();
await page.keyboard.type("20200903");
await page.waitFor(500);
await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
await page.waitFor(5000);
// Screenshot to check page state
await page.screenshot({

    path: "./screenshot.png",

    fullPage: true

});
await page.waitFor(500);
// Times out
await click(page, '#contentRepeater > div.repeater-viewport > div.repeater-canvas.scrolling > div > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(3) > div > div > div > div')
```

}

And if I call the find Iframe method before clicking on the selector:

```
await findFrame(page, "contentbuilder");
```

Nothing really happens and it errors with a JSHandler issue, has anyone had anything similar  happen? Could it be that the issue is Iframes? The odd thing is that the searchField input and keypress goes through just fine. Moreover, it is the same iframe, so I shouldn't have to call findFrame two times.

beforeAction:

```
async function beforeAction(page, timeout) {
if (timeout != null) {
await page.waitFor(timeout);
}

var isLoading = await isPageLoading(page);

while (isLoading) {
await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
isLoading = await isPageLoading(page);
 }
}
```

Comment: is your selector inside the iframe `contentbuilder`?

Comment: (1) is `searchField.focus()` not async on purpose? (2) can you share the code for function used in `beforeAction(page, timeout)`? (3) what is the error msg exactly what you referred as "JSHandler issue"?

Comment: @Ben Correct, the selector is within the iframe, so I should not need to find the Iframe again after it proceeds with the "Search". I did try finding the frame again, that did not solve the issue

Comment: @theDavidBarton Good question, I actually missed this, thanks, it should be async, however the code still runs fine there. I have updated the question with the beforeAction method now. When it comes to the JSHandler error it states _jshandles can be evaluated only in the context they were created!_

Comment: A bit of clarification, the error pops up only when I call the findFrame method twice, but realistically I should not have to do it.

Comment: thanks @KristapsL for sharing the `beforeAction` function! I am honestly terrified to ask for the newly involved "`isPageLoading`" function's code as I can imagine it will contain another unfamiliar function :D based on the code you gave it is not possible to run your code locally so I can only guess, you need to solve it by debugging the exact line that throws the "jshandles can be evaluated..." error. that one is a typical navigation handling case, see: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3568 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53372923/

Comment: Then if the selector is within the iframe `contentbuilder`, why not pass `contentBuilderFrame` as argument to the `click` function instead of `page`? My understanding is that you need to look for the selector from the iframe and not from the global page but I'm no Puppeteer expert and I might be mistaken.

Comment: @theDavidBarton Thank you for the comment, I'll have a look and keep it in mind if I ever run into a similar issue again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we came up with the answer in the comments, I'm posting it here for other people who come across this question.

As the targeted selector is in an iframe (`contentbuilder`), the context to be passed as argument the function `click` is not `page` but the iframe element: `contentBuilderFrame`.